# sending push notification from spring boot

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, sqlite, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an application that has ***spring boot*** backend and ***android*** application in front .
also it has a **SQLITE** database too , I'm wondering to know how I can send push notification from back-end to my android application on the specific times that has been saved as a column in database.
for example we have a row that has a column named 'time' , I just want to read that time and send push notification from server to front on time we have read .
I've heard about FCM but I don't know how should I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a google android developer account and follow this guide:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications